# Biphasic T wave caused by digitalis toxicity

Tags: human-biology, physiology, homework, cardiology

> Digitalis is a drug that can be used during coronary insufficiency to
>   increase the strength of cardiac muscle contraction. But when
>   overdosages of digitalis are given, depolarization duration in one
>   part of the ventricles may be increased out of proportion to that of
>   other parts. As a result, nonspecific changes, such as T wave
>   inversion or biphasic T waves, may occur in one or more of the
>   electrocardiographic leads. A biphasic T wave caused by excessive
>   administration of digitalis is shown in Figure.

[image]

Therefore, changes in the T wave during digitalis administration are often the earliest signs of digitalis toxicity.

I was reading about it in **Guyton and Hall Physiology (volume 1, heart , chapter 12)** and there was nothing about this that answers my questions.

And my questions are:

- Why is **T wave** more affected by digitalis toxicity?
- Why does it cause **Biphasic** T wave?

Comment: Can you reference the reading you did on *why* this might be? Or perhaps write what you think? It's considered a requisite on biology.se that at least some research into the question you ask is carried out and presented with your question.

Comment: @anonoodnurse I wrote the reference in my post. and I don't have no idea about it, but I'm really enthusiastic to know and think about answer of question.

Answer (score 2):

Digitalis (which was by the way originally synthesized from [Digitalis Purpurea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitalis_purpurea)) has two mechanisms of action:

> The action by which digoxin improves contractility appears to be inhibition of the sarcolemmal Na$^+$K$^+$-ATPase "pump", normally responsible for maintaining transmembrane Na$^+$ and K$^+$ gradients
>
> The major therapeutic electrical effect of digoxin occurs at the AV node, where it slows conduction velocity and increases refractoriness.

So it has a mechanical and an electrical mechanism. About the toxicity:

> For example, in atrial and ventricular Purkinje fibers, a high dixogin concentration has three important actions that may lead to dangerous arrhythmias:
>
> 1. less negative resting potential
> 2. decreased action potential duration
> 3. enhanced automaticity

All quotes are from the book *Pathophysiology of Heart Disease* by Leonard S. Lilly, 5th edition.

So, I would assume one of the three (or a combination of them) is the reason for the biphasic T-wave. I hope someone more experienced can improve upon this answer.

This maybe has something to do with the relative [refractory period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractory_period_%28physiology%29) ending during the T-wave.

Also, since the figure is from lead I, you can use that information for looking at where the net electrical axis is pointing at during the T-wave. Refer to the [hexaxial system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexaxial_reference_system).

Comment: It is not written but it should relate to lead I .